# Vertically aligning textsuperscript and textsubscript together

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

I would like to show both super and subscript together some text.

I tried this     `sometext\textsuperscript{1}\textsubscript{2}`

But 2 does not show up right below 1.

Thanks for your help. Also how can I show 1 & 2 in front of sometext as well.

regards
Aku

I tried some both the answers posted below and here is the attachment. I was trying to put 2 digit number 16 and 32 in superscript and subscript. [image]

[image]

Comment: then you didn't put it into braces: `^{16}_{32}`. That was the behaviour Alan already pointed out.

Comment: This is also an argument in favour of never leaving the braces off after `^` and `_` in answering these types of questions. :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

without using directly math and with colors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\SPSB#1#2{\rlap{\textsuperscript{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}\SB{#2}}
\def\SP#1{\textsuperscript{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
\def\SB#1{\textsubscript{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\huge
sometext\SPSB{1}{2} more text

sometext\SP{1} more\SB{2} text\SP{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why it is reducing the text size of "sometex" & "more text" to scriptsize. It should be in the normal size and only sub-superscript should reduce in size

Comment: @Aku: I cannot see it. Give an example.

Comment: sorry, it was the document view, because of which I thought it coming as scriptsize. It works just fine

Comment: The coloring unnecessarily complicates this answer. `\rlap` is all you need.

Answer (score 12):

use it in math mode, digits are always set in upright mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\begin{document}
\Huge
sometext\textsuperscript{1}\textsubscript{2}

sometext$^1_2$ \qquad$^1_2$sometext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Math mode:

```
sometext$^1_2$
```

or (with `amsmath`):

```
$\text{sometext}^1_2$
```

Comment: Remember that if you need non-numeric sub- and superscripts, you'll need to enclose them in `text{}` (from `amsmath`). e.g. `sometext$^{\text{super}}_{\text{sub}}$` otherwise the text won't come out correctly.

Comment: That's right. But it's not clear whether `sometext\textsuperscript{1}\textsubscript{2}` *should* be in text mode. Afterall, numbers are always typeset in the same typeface by default.

Answer (score 3):

To typeset "sometext" followed by "'1' above '2'" you can simply use:

```tex
sometext\rlap{\textsuperscript{1}}\textsubscript{2}
```

This will only work nicely if the superscript is longer than or equal to the subscript in width.  If the subscript is longer, place it first and inside the `rlap`.

Comment: Is this, maybe, back-to-front?  I'm finding the shorter needs to be placed in the rlap.