# How to typeset indices before a symbol?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

I know how to write a usual index with the help of the underscore, but I seem to be unable to find out how to write an (upper/lower) index in front of a letter/text.

These kind of indices are common in chemistry.

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334/non-kludgey-left-subscripts has what you need.

Comment: These two questions might answer your question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8255/superscript-and-subscript-together

Comment: Since you want to typeset chemical formulas, maybe the `mhchem` package helps.

Comment: Although you can solve the problem in the ways mentioned below, you should still consider searching [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/search/?search=chemistry&search_type=description) for chemistry specific packages that are supported by your system. These packages will give the "look and feel" that a professionally typeset chemistry publication will have.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to supply a "fake" object for TeX to put indices to:

```
${}^1_2X^3_4$
```

However, for chemistry typesetting you should use one of the specialized packages, such as [`mhchem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem). This example is taken from `mhchem` documentation:

```
\ce{^{227}_{90}Th+}
```

It will typeset the symbol for a positive Thorium ion with a charge of 90 and atomic mass of 227.

[image: example]

Comment: I had about the same answer, but you were quicker :). Since I already hat the screenshot I added it to your answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: As I use MathJax this works great!

Answer (score 14):

[`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) provides among other useful things the `prescript` command for this. Verbose, but useful if you don't want to fiddle with negative spaces and fake objects.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
{}^{4}_{12}\mathbf{C}^{5+}_{2}
\quad
\prescript{14}{2}{\mathbf{C}}^{5+}_{2}
\quad
\prescript{4}{12}{\mathbf{C}}^{5+}_{2}
\quad
\prescript{14}{}{\mathbf{C}}^{5+}_{2}
\quad
\prescript{}{2}{\mathbf{C}}^{5+}_{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The easiest in this case would be to use the [`leftidx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/leftidx). Taken directly from the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/leftidx/leftidx.pdf):

```
\usepackage{leftidx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/leftidx
...
$\leftidx{_1^2}{\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)}{_3^4}$
```

[image: Leftidx]

The package offers the command `\leftidx{<left indices>}{<stuff>}{<right indices>}`.

Answer (score 6):

I just saw this package a few minutes ago and it has a good example of this. There are probably other packages for Chemistry usage though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}
$\tensor*[^{14}_6]{\mathrm{C}}{}$
\end{document}
```

This example is directly copied form the [tensor package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tensor).