# superscript asterisk on the left side of different symbols (math mode)

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I need to add superscript asterisks to the left side of different symbols like `+,\cdot,\leq,\mathbb{R}`.

I read several different solutions to similar questions, which recommended either `\prescript`, which is ugly, since there is a huge space between the asterisk and `\leq` or `\sideset` from `amsmath`, which refuses to work on symbols like `+`.

Does anyone know some universal pretty solution, which puts the asterisk neatly before this symbols?

Comment: There are multiple options: [How to typeset indices before a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25975/5764); [Left and right subscript](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11542/5764); [Superscripts before a letter in math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30554/5764).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not simply using a "presuperscript"; what we need is to add the asterisk and keeping the meaning of the symbols; moreover, the asterisk seems needing to be nearer the symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\hplus}{\mathbin{^*\!+}}
\newcommand{\hcdot}{\mathbin{^*\!\cdot}}
\newcommand{\hleq}{\mathrel{^*\!}\leq}
\newcommand{\hR}{{}^*\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
$a\hcdot b \hplus c \hleq d \in \hR$
\end{document}
```

(The "h" is for "hyper", as I suspect this is for nonstandard analysis.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about mathbin and mathrel before. And yes, this is indeed for non-standard analysis.