# Numbers under each other

Tags: math-mode

How do you put numbers under each other in LaTeX?

For example: In physics, when describing decay, a carbon atom with a mass number of 14 and an atomic number 6 is denoted in the following way:

`$^{14}_6 C$` however, I want the 14 and 6 to be aligned. How?

Comment: See the tensor package. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tensor

Comment: Or the `mhchem` package and then `\ce{^{14}_6 C}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to typeset indices before a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25975/5764)

Comment: There's also the [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package with `\ch{^{14}6C}`.