# \newcommand and \prescript aren't working together

Tags: macros, mathtools

The code

```
\newcommand{\AMod}[1]{\prescript{}{#1}\text{Mod}}
\AMod{A}
```

causes the following error:

```
! Argument of \text@ has an extra }.
```

The error does not occur when I replace the `\prescript` subscript with an ordinary subscript using `_`.  I'd like to use `\prescript`, since it looks much nicer.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Related: [How to typeset indices before a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25975/5764)

Comment: Also, please do not use `\text` for this context. It is meant to provide a textual comment in display math. It is **not** supposed to be used just to make something upright (which it doesn't actually do, it will be italic in an italic context. You should consider `\mathrm ` or similar in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The  `\prescript` command takes three parameters, the third of which is the thing to which the pre-scripts should be attached.
Hence

```
\newcommand{\AMod}[1]{\prescript{}{#1}{\text{Mod}}}
```

should work fine.

In your attempt the call `\prescript{}{#1}\text{Mod}` parses as `\prescript{}{#1}{\text}{Mod}` which means that the third argument is just the macro `\text`. When the third argument gets used by the definition of `\prescript`, it tries to fetch an argument for itself but `\prescript` uses it assuming it is just some math and this causes the error.